# Cluster phrases of similar meaning in R

Tags: r, tm

I want to cluster phrases of similar meaning and plot a dendrogram. I also want to show a list of grouped phrases.
I can only seem to show a dendrogram with the index number as the output and not the phrase itself. 
Also i have hundreds of phrases i would like to show as a grouped list sorted by largest group.

```
strings.to.cluster <- c("how do i find the bus times", 
                    "where do i find the bus time tables", 
                    "where is the bus times",
                    "is there a bus time table", 
                    "where is the bus time table", 
                    "what is the meaning of life", 
                    "the quick brown fox", 
                    "how do i find the bus times", 
                    "where is the bus times")
library(tm)
library(Matrix)
x <- TermDocumentMatrix( Corpus( VectorSource( strings.to.cluster ) ) )
y <- sparseMatrix( i=x$i, j=x$j, x=x$v, dimnames = dimnames(x) )  
plot( hclust(dist(t(y))) )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the tm package and `sparseMatrix` you are turning the strings into words. Your dendrogram will be of the words and not of the sentences. Check what happens if you do not transpose your matrix and use `plot(hclust(dist(y)))`. You will see that you get the words plotted, but not your sentences.

Using the package stringdist we can calculate the distance between all the sentences and then use this distance matrix for hclust. Using the option useNames = "strings" we add the strings as labels to the distance matrix and these will be used as labels in the hclust object.

```
cl <- hclust(stringdist::stringdistmatrix(strings.to.cluster, method = "cosine", useNames = "strings"))
plot(cl)
```

[image]

If you are more interested in the separate word clusters you might want to check the functions available in the quanteda package. But definitely read up on topic modeling.